# Does this time format have a name?

Tags: .net, datetime, time, format

Does this time format have a name?

2.08:49:25.4601683

This file format is used in the project I'm working on and the back-end is built with .net. I don't have anyone to ask about this and googling this format doesn't give any results. I need to know the behavior of this time format in order to implement logic related to it.

Comment: What time / date is represented by the example in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out this is the format:The Constant ("c") Format Specifier.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings#the-constant-c-format-specifier